# Repeating a character across the full width of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, viewport

I am trying to write a function using `JavaScript` and `jQuery` (since I'm already using `jQuery` for my site) to detect the width of the view port and output a character repeated across the full width.

I am trying to make a website that looks like a `unix` terminal and I would like the table headers to use the equal sign to repeat across the width of the screen (tables are set to `width: 100%;`). I know I probably could just make a simple image of the equal sign and set it to `repeat-x` using `CSS` on an empty header row but I prefer it to be text. I have been playing around with arrays and this is what I have so far.

```
var windowWidth =$(window).width();
document.write( array( windowWidth ) ).join( '=' ) );
```

I know this is broken, but that is where I left off because I haven't been able to figure out what search terms I should be using to find an answer. So if anyone wouldn't mind either helping me write this or point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

Comment: does this do anything? Because you add the `join()` method to your `document.write()` instead of your `array`

Comment: Ahh yes. I have one too many parentheses. I put that in to illustrate what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can probably be improved, but you could do it by:

- Appending a single character to the body, and get its width, then remove it.
- Divide the width of the body by the width of the character to get the number of times to repeat the character.

#### Example

```
var $char = $('<span>').css({ padding: 0, margin: 0 }).text('=').appendTo('body'),
    charWidth = $char.width(),
    numberOfChars = parseInt(( $('body').width() / charWidth ).toFixed(), 10);

$char.remove();
document.write( Array(numberOfChars).join('=') );
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLtk4/13/)

Answer (score 0):

my take on it:

```
for (
    var x = Math.floor(
    $("body").append("<span>=</span>").width() / $($("body").children()[0]).width());

    x > 1;

    x-- && $("body").append("<span>=</span>")
);
```

change `$("body")` to whatever element you wanna add your stuff into.

http://jsfiddle.net/8suma/