# Repeating a character to create a border?

Tags: html, css

I'm in a pickle. The website I am coding has a design element that consists of a series of forward slashes bordering the bottom of each header. Currently I have the design as a background image for the H* tags, but it's not quite working for some widths and there is cropping...

[image]

I want it so that the slashes aren't cropped, but for the life of me I cannot figure this out with just CSS & HTML. I would be fine with this if all the headers on the website are the same width, but they vary (plus, there is responsiveness to consider).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: CSS that I have tried...

https://jsfiddle.net/be5fcwjn/1/

```
h4 {padding: 0 0 52px 0; background: url('https://s4.postimg.org/4kmb83h19/slashes.png') 50% 100% no-repeat; background-size: auto 17px; color: #008ea8; font-size: 1.571em; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 1px; text-align: center;}
```

And another attempt:

https://jsfiddle.net/jznfbvuw/1/

```
h4 {
 padding: 0 0 52px 0; color: #008ea8; font-size: 1.571em; font-weight: 600; letter-spacing: 1px; text-align: center;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 0px 0px 17px;
 -moz-border-image: url('https://s3.postimg.org/s2ikelx9f/slash.png') 0 0 17 repeat;
 -webkit-border-image: url('https://s3.postimg.org/s2ikelx9f/slash.png') 0 0 17 repeat;
 -o-border-image: url('https://s3.postimg.org/s2ikelx9f/slash.png') 0 0 17 repeat;
 border-image: url('https://s3.postimg.org/s2ikelx9f/slash.png') 0 0 17 fill repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using CSS `transform: skewX(...)` + `::after`?

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor</h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
  font-family: "Avenir", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 400px;
}

h1:after {
  background-image: url(http://i63.tinypic.com/29oo77r.png);
  background-size: 10px 100%;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: skewX(-35deg);
}
```

**LIVE:** https://jsfiddle.net/267cp7p3/

The idea is to use vertical lines as background, and then skew it.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Aziz had a solution that doesn't use images, but I will keep yours in mind as well if images become a requirement. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure CSS solution using pseudo selector `::before` and `::after`. One for the stripes and the other acts as a mask to hide last character:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #FFF;
}

.title {
  color: #01c0e3;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0.5em 1em 0;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title::before, .title::after {
content: '//////////////////////\
////////////////////////////////\
////////////////////////////////\
////////////////////////////////';
  display: block;
  width: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  bottom: -70%;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.title::before {
    content: '/';
    width: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
    right: 5px;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    opacity: 1;
    color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Featured News + Events</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta voluptas sapiente vitae consectetur ipsa assumenda repellat, recusandae hic, cupiditate obcaecati, officia quod itaque aliquid veniam quia natus iure dignissimos pariatur.</p>

<h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>Suscipit animi tenetur cupiditate ducimus, tempora molestias autem ab voluptate nostrum aspernatur deserunt tempore necessitatibus vero eligendi at dolorem asperiores, natus nesciunt error odit consequatur, esse veniam. Illum molestiae, veniam?</p>

<h3 class="title">Repeating a character with CSS</h3>
<p>At consequuntur, tempora blanditiis dolorem vero! Temporibus nemo cupiditate alias perspiciatis maiores perferendis, quasi, autem ab dolorum, fuga adipisci fugiat accusantium. Eos possimus excepturi tenetur, commodi minima blanditiis esse ratione.</p>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/mxt6pgp6/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a repeated linear gradient:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.title {
  color: #01c0e3;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0.5em 1em 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.title::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: .75em;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-75deg, transparent 45%, #01c0e3 45%,
                                            #01c0e3 55%, transparent 55%);
  background-size: .3em;
  background-repeat: round;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">Featured News + Events</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta voluptas sapiente vitae consectetur ipsa assumenda repellat, recusandae hic, cupiditate obcaecati, officia quod itaque aliquid veniam quia natus iure dignissimos pariatur.</p>

<h2 class="title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
<p>Suscipit animi tenetur cupiditate ducimus, tempora molestias autem ab voluptate nostrum aspernatur deserunt tempore necessitatibus vero eligendi at dolorem asperiores, natus nesciunt error odit consequatur, esse veniam. Illum molestiae, veniam?</p>

<h3 class="title">Repeating a character with CSS</h3>
<p>At consequuntur, tempora blanditiis dolorem vero! Temporibus nemo cupiditate alias perspiciatis maiores perferendis, quasi, autem ab dolorum, fuga adipisci fugiat accusantium. Eos possimus excepturi tenetur, commodi minima blanditiis esse ratione.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `border-image` property, create an image with the slashes and then use it with the `border-image`, read this article to understand how it works

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/

Comment: I tried this, but the same cropping effect happens. :(

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out, but it is not a favorable solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/8suma/1/

```
for (
  var x = Math.floor(
  $('h4').append("<span>/</span>").width() / $($('h4').children()[0]).width());
  x > 1;
  x-- && $('h4').append("<span>/</span>")
);
```

It's based off of this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24143098/4106957

I'd rather not have a script to create the slashes (it may slow down the site if there's a lot of headers), but if it works, it works?

If anyone has a better solution, please let me know!